# How to create a color scale legend with Vue.js and D3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js

I have my map working in Vue.js and D3. It took me a while to get to this point, but I found some great tutorials to follow.

[image]

The data shown is each state's average CC debt per person. I'm interpolating each state's color with:

```
return d3.scaleLinear().domain([6726, 10685]).range(["white", "red"])
```

Where `6726` is the lowest value in my data set and `10685` is the highest value.

I'm looking at the D3 docs for legends and I can't make heads or tails of it. I'd like to experiment with displaying a color scale showing the same range with various steps in the range. Perhaps splitting the range into quarters would do.

Maybe something similar to this:

[image]

https://observablehq.com/@d3/color-legend